# Observer Arraylist static Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an integration of a bluetooth sdk,

It forces me to have a static arraylist where the sdk module is hosting the read data, this statement is in Java

```
public ArrayList<ReaderDevice> tagsList = new ArrayList<>();
```

In my Kotlin activity I have the static reference

```
   lateinit var sharedObjects: SharedObjects
```

To get this list of my fragments I use

```
HomeActivity.sharedObjects.tagsList
```

What I need is "some way" no matter how "dirty" to be able to have a "listener"-"observer" to know from my fragments when a new element is added to take some action x

Try to create the observable like this

```
//fragment
viewmodel.setReadTagsList.onNext(HomeActivity.sharedObjects.tagsList)

//viewmodel
val setReadTagsList = PublishSubject.create<List<ReaderDevice>>()

private val _tags = BehaviorSubject.create<List<ReaderDevice>>()

        setReadTagsList
            .bind(_tags)
            .disposedBy(disposeBag)

        setReadTagsList
            .withLatestFrom(_tags){_, o1 -> o1}
            .map { "${it.size}" }
            .bind(_errorMessage)
            .disposedBy(disposeBag)
```

but only when I do the "onnext" can I get the size, otherwise it doesn't refresh, I guess it's because it "is copied" but it doesn't have the same reference, can I somehow put the static reference to my viewmodel propertys? I'm lost how to see this list

Comment: Sounds like you want a `SharedFlow`.

Comment: can you show my a example?